# DateTime.Now within a statement

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In the below `thisIsAlwaysTrue` should always be true.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
bool thisIsAlwaysTrue = d == d;
```

But does DateTime.Now work in such a way that isThisAlwaysTrue is guaranteed to be true? Or can the clock change between references to the Now property?

```
bool isThisAlwaysTrue = DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The clock can definitely change between two back-to-back calls to DateTime.Now;

Comment: This answer is correct but doesn't answer the poster's question. (I state this only so that casual readers won't expect that 'thisIsAlwaysTrue' in the code above could ever be false.)

Comment: But that's the point: in the statement above, isThisAlwaysTrue will indeed be false every once in a while, namely when the real-time clock tick changes after the first but before the second call to DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 8):

The DateTime.Now property is volatile, meaning it definitely can change between uses.  But the variable you assign it to is not volatile.

So this should always set result to true:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
bool result = d == d;
```

It assigns the value returned by DateTime.Now to the d variable, not the property itself.  Thus d will always equal d in that code.

But this will not always set result to true:

```
bool result = DateTime.Now == DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have to recommend you try this for yourself.  This code takes a fraction of second in the Release build:

```
using System;

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    while (DateTime.UtcNow == DateTime.UtcNow) ;
    Console.WriteLine("oops");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

I trust it will repro well.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is immutable, so it will never ever change once assigned. Your call to DateTime.Now doesn't "link" them - it just assigns whatever **value** DateTime.Now is at the time of calling to the variable d - it will not assign some sort of reference.

So if you have a delay like this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now; // Let's assume it's 9:05:10
Thread.Sleep(100);
Console.WriteLine(d); // will still be 9:05:10, even though it's much later now
```